# How to do pivot operation on multiple columns on python pandas or big query. Preferably on big query

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, pivot, transpose

original data:

[image]

how the data would look like after required transformation:

[image]

I have tried melt function in python pandas, but I am only able to pivot on one column. I am sure I must be missing something.

Comment: kindly post data, not pics

Comment: Since no usebale data, look at stack/unstack and pd.pivot_table()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
execute immediate (
with types as (
  select 
    array_to_string(types, ',') values_list,
    regexp_replace(array_to_string(types, ','), r'([^,]+)', r'"\1"') columns_list
  from (
    select regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(t), r'"([^""]+)":') types
    from (
      select * except(Country, Branch, Category)
      from `project.dataset.your_table` limit 1
    ) t
  )
), categories as (
  select distinct Category  
  from `project.dataset.your_table`
)
select '''
select Country, Branch, Output, ''' || 
  (select string_agg(''' 
  max(if(Category = "''' || Category || '''", val, null)) as ''' || Category ) 
  from categories)
|| ''' 
from (
  select Country, Branch, Category, 
    type[offset(offset)] Output, val 
  from `project.dataset.your_table` t,
  unnest([''' || values_list || ''']) val with offset,
  unnest([struct([''' || columns_list || '''] as type)])
)
group by Country, Branch, Output
'''
from types
);
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]